# c# textbox autocomplete from sql table

Tags: c#, sql, textbox

I need to search tables in `combobox1` with the text user will enter in `autoCompleteTextbox1` and it can be `itemcode` or `itemname`

but I get error says:

> Additional information: The variable name '@name' has already been
>   declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

```
if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        cm.Connection = cn;
        if (autoCompleteTextbox1.Text == "")
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AutoCompleteStringCollection namecollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            string searchFor = "%" + autoCompleteTextbox1.Text + "%"; //the string the user entered.
            string tableName = comboBox1.Text;
            cm.CommandText = @"SELECT  distinct(itmcode+''+itmname) AS name FROM " + tableName + " WHERE itmcode Like @name OR itmname LIKE @name";

            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", searchFor);
            SqlDataReader rea = cm.ExecuteReader();
            if (rea.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (rea.Read())
                    namecollection.Add(rea["name"].ToString());
            }
            rea.Close();

            autoCompleteTextbox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            autoCompleteTextbox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            autoCompleteTextbox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namecollection;
```

what is the error in my code and how to fix it plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cm` variable represents a command.

Because `cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", searchFor);` is failing with the error `The variable name '@name' has already been declared.` you can conclude that the `cm` variable is living longer then this block of code.

You can either

1) Reinitialize the command every time (this is something most people do).
  e.g.

```
     cm = new SqlCommand(); //Assumes sql server
     cm.Connection = cn;
```

or

2) Check the cmd.Parameters for the @name parameter and then add if it doesn't exist and then set it .

```
if (!(cmd.Parameters.Contains("@name")
{
     cmd.Paramters.Add("@name",SqlDbType.Varchar)
}

cmd.Paramters["@name"].Value = serachFor;
```

Notes on SQL Injection with  `FROM " + tableName + " WHERE.`

comboBox1.Text is what populates tableName. It is only a dangerous string if it's a string that the users can change (for example a web page). If it's a WPF or Window Forms app then it's not dangerous.*

If comboBox1.Text is from a web page then the best thing you can do is use a white list to  validate that the string hasn't been altered and if it has then to not return any results. For example

```
if (!ValidTableNames.Contains(tableName)) 
    return;
```

What's nice is you already have the white list since you populated the combo box with it.

*Technically they could change the values with debugger tools but at that point they can just change the command text directly anyway.

Comment: thanks for reply and I need to ask u how to Reinitialize the command every time ?

Comment: my problem is that I want to use parameters because of sql injection

Comment: got it working now but one problem left :)  .. the data appears in the autocomplete are the data in the 2 columns combined next to eachother but what I wanted is to show matches of what I entered In the textbox means if I entered a value that was found in itmcode column shows only results in column itmcode and if I enter a value was found in itmname column it show only names

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
string searchFor = "%" + autoCompleteTextbox1.Text + "%"; //the string the user entered.
            string tableName = comboBox1.Text;
            cm.CommandText = @"SELECT  distinct(itmcode+''+itmname) AS name FROM " + tableName + " WHERE itmcode Like @name OR itmname LIKE @name";

            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", searchFor);
```

whith

```
string searchFor = "%" + autoCompleteTextbox1.Text + "%";
string tableName = comboBox1.Text;
cm.CommandText = @"SELECT  distinct(itmcode+''+itmname) AS name FROM " + tableName + " WHERE itmcode Like '" + searchFor + "' OR itmname LIKE '" + searchFor + "'";
```

Comment: This just begs for SQL injection.

Comment: how about replacing quotes inside the string with \' with the Replace function